# error: cannot list snaps: empty query after updating snapd

Tags: ubuntu-core

I' ve updated snapd to version 2.11+0.16.04 and when i do "sudo snap find" it displays me "error: cannot list snaps: empty query"

Please help me!

Answer (score 2):

On the one hand, there is a bug: the error message does not tell you what you need to do to fix it. It doesn't really even tell you what you're doing wrong in a language you can understand.

On the other hand, what you're doing wrong is that `snap find` needs an argument, a search query, so it can search for it. Before if you didn't enter a query it would run an empty query, which returned 100 arbitrary snaps from the store. That is expensive and never what the user wanted, so in 2.11 we stopped doing that.

---

If for what ever reason you really *do* need to get a list of all snaps, feel free to query the store directly; it has a [public, documented API](http://search.apps.ubuntu.com/docs/#snap-specific-endpoints).

For example, something like this:

```
$ http --print b https://search.apps.ubuntu.com/api/v1/snaps/search Accept:application/hal+json X-Ubuntu-Series:16 X-Ubuntu-Architecture:amd64 X-Ubuntu-Series:16 X-Ubuntu-Wire-Protocol:1 fields==summary,package_name size==2 | jq -r '._embedded["clickindex:package"][] | "\(.package_name): \(.summary)"'
test-snapd-cups-control-consumer: Basic cups-control consumer snap
test-snapd-fuse-consumer: Basic fuse consumer snap
```

if you're using `http` from the homonymous snap, checkout `http snapd:///v2/find` also.

Comment: Ok. So if you stoped doing the command syntax "sudo snap find" with no arguments, how can i get a list of all snaps are avalible for me to install.

Comment: you can't. Why do you want that? (what is your use case?)

Comment: Ok. If this syntax cant be used anymore I will gonna use uappexplorer to see all the snaps that are avalible for me to install. P.S : I am not a developer so, I cant uderstand and use this API.

Comment: Ok meanwhile I've reading with more atention that API and I will try this method and if I can't use it, I will use uappexplorer

Answer (score 1):

You should try

> snap find .

(http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/command-sudo-snap-find-error-not-a-bug)

Comment: I know. I've readet this post a few weeks ago.